# Speed up FinancialData execution?

Tags: performance-tuning, curated-data

When I do e.g.

```
GE = FinancialData["GE", "OHLCV", "Jan. 1, 1918"]; // Timing
```

> `{2.67188, Null}`

The output claims that the command was executed within 2.6 seconds. However, if I track seconds on the windows clock while the cell is working it actually takes over 10 seconds until it finishes.

I suspect that this slowdown is due to `FinancialData` having a ton of quality of life features, like dynamically displaying what it is currently doing in a blue box during evaluation. If all I care about is getting the data into the list `GE` as fast as possible, is there a way to tweak the input to speed things up?

Comment: 1) You might want to use AbsoluteTiming instead of Timing. 2) I don't think that what you've described is the real cause.

Comment: So, you could try to be more direct with an EntityValue call. Although that can be a bit difficult to construct with a dated object ```Dated[Entity["Financial", "NYSE:GE"], DateObject["Jan. 14, 1978"]]["Open"]```

Comment: But I bet the timing is mostly a factor of the speed of the response to the API call FinancialData is making.